# Given a rotated rectangle in Inkscape (svg format), find coordinates in Python

Tags: python, svg, inkscape, coordinate-transformation

Given the following rectangles in Inkscape .svg format, I want to find the absolute coordinates, of all four corners, of the second rectangle (in Python). Without writing my own matrix-transformations, or anything really complex.

[image: two rectangles with one rotated]

You'd think there would be a library for this sort of thing. In fact, I found [Python SVG Extensions - simpletransform.py](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Python_modules_for_extensions#simpletransform.py), that sounds like it would to it. But it's in the `deprecated` folder of my installed Inkscape, with this notice:

> This directory IS NOT a module path, to denote this we are using a dash in the name and there is no '**init**.py'

And is not really importable, as-is. I might just try copy/pasting the code, but I don't have a warm-fuzzy that it will work at all.

And there seem to be a lot of questions/articles about "removing transforms", but they all seem to be related to "accidentally" added transforms.

Just to make things more complex - it looks like the x/y coordinates of the second rectangle - refer to the corner of the bounding-box, *not* the actual rectangle corner. I still don't really understand Inkscape's funky coordinate-system - it seems like the GUI is backwards from the actual objects. When I mouse-over the rectangle, its coordinates don't match what I expect to see.

Oh, and all units are set to pixels (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very interesting question.  Inkscape transform (or transform in computer graphics) can be quite complicated.  This webpage has some good information on how transform works in Inkscape extensions.

https://inkscapetutorial.org/transforms.html

For your specific example, the direct answer is that Inkscape system extension (after version 1.0) has a `Transform` class (in `transforms.py` module), which has a method `apply_to_point` that can calculate the absolute coordinates.

More specifically, the following extension (inx and py files, under menu item Extension -> Custom -> Transform Element 2) draws the rectangle in your example with the `Rectangle` class, calculates the 4 corners with `apply_to_point` method, draws a path with those 4 points. The result two rectangles overlap each other, so we know the calculation is correct.

Code in `transform2.inx` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inkscape-extension xmlns="http://www.inkscape.org/namespace/inkscape/extension">
    <name>Transform Element 2</name>
    <id>user.transform2</id>
    <effect>
        <object-type>all</object-type>
        <effects-menu>
            <submenu name="Custom"/>
        </effects-menu>
    </effect>
    <script>
        <command location="inx" interpreter="python">transform2.py</command>
    </script>
</inkscape-extension>
```

Code in `transform2.py` file

```
import inkex
from inkex import Rectangle, Transform
from inkex import Vector2d

class NewElement(inkex.GenerateExtension):
    container_label = 'transform'
    container_layer = True

    def generate(self):
        self.style = {'fill' : 'none', 'stroke' : '#000000', 
            'stroke-width' : self.svg.unittouu('2px')}
        self.style_red = {'fill' : 'none', 'stroke' : '#FF0000', 
            'stroke-width' : self.svg.unittouu('.5px')}
        rects = self.add_rect()
        for r in rects:
            yield r

    def add_rect(self):

        rect = Rectangle.new(15, 5, 20, 5)
        rect.style = self.style 
        tr = Transform('rotate(45)')
        rect.transform = tr

        el = rect
        pt_top_left = tr.apply_to_point(Vector2d(el.left, el.top))
        pt_top_right = tr.apply_to_point(Vector2d(el.right, el.top))
        pt_right_bottom = tr.apply_to_point(Vector2d(el.right, el.bottom)) 
        pt_left_bottom = tr.apply_to_point(Vector2d(el.left, el.bottom)) 

        path = inkex.PathElement()
        path.update(**{
            'style': self.style_red,
            'inkscape:label': 'redline',
            'd': 'M ' + str(pt_top_left.x) + ',' + str(pt_top_left.y) +
                ' L ' + str(pt_top_right.x) + ',' + str(pt_top_right.y) +
                ' L ' + str(pt_right_bottom.x) + ',' + str(pt_right_bottom.y) + 
                ' L ' + str(pt_left_bottom.x) + ',' + str(pt_left_bottom.y) + 
                ' z'})
        return [rect, path]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    NewElement().run()
```

Here is the result of the extension run:

[image: extension result]

Furthermore, the `simpletransform.py` documentation you referenced in your post is written for Inkscape System Extension before version 1.0.  The code is written with Python 2.X version.  Even though you can find a copy of the file that comes with Inkscape 0.92.X, you will need to spend time to understand the code and rewrite it to be Python 3 compatible, and then you can use it in your program.  It is not really recommended for anyone to do that.

As for Inkscape extension units, this webpage also has some good information on this topic.

https://inkscapetutorial.org/units-and-coordinate-systems.html

Comment: Looks interesting. Just to be clear - are the points `pt_top_left`, etc, the absolute-coordinates of the rectangle? I'm not trying to display the rotated rectangle, but find the pixel-coordinates for use in other tools. Additionally, I'm not quite clear on `inkex` - is it a built-in to the Inkscape install? Or a third-party library?

Comment: Yes, those are absolute coordinates. Inkex is like the Inkscape extension development Python framework which comes with Inkscape installation.